# Fetching multiple objects while passing argument to constructor (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to fetch multiple rows into instances while passing an argument to the constructor(the PDO connection). I could fetch one row at a time and then construct them  but I am looking for a one line solution.

```
class Member {

        // PDO connection
        public $conn;

        public $Members_ID;
        public $Members_FirstName;
        public $Members_LastName;


        function __construct($conn){         
            $this->conn= $conn;
        }


        // Returns an array of Members with the email address that is given
        // (Multiple members can have the same email)
        public static function getMembersFromEmailAddress($emailAddress, $conn){

            try 
            {
                $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Members_Email ='". $emailAddress ."'"); 

               //HERE I WANT MEMBERS TO BE AN ARRAY OF MEMBER OBJECTS
                $members = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new Member($conn));
                return $members
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

}
```

Comment: why would that be incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
$args= array();
$args[] = $conn;

$members = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Member', $args);
```

`FETCH_INTO` is used for adding data into an already existing class, so in your case using `FETCH_CLASS` makes more sense.

---

Side note: Since you are already using PDO, you might as well take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). This provides the benefit of not having to worry about SQL injections.

The only thing in your code that would change is:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Members_Email = :member_email");
$result = $stmt->execute(array(":member_email" => $emailAddress));
```

Comment: `Having no worries` in case if you set the charset to `UTF8` and disabled an emulation of prepares. Otherwise that's just WRONG

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are only fetching one row, into one object.

You need to fetch in a loop, and add to an array:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new Member($conn)) {
    $members[] = $row;
}
return $members;
```

Comment: Your code is not what he needs. FETC_CLASS is here for the purpose he wants.

Answer (score 0):

you have got a design flaw.
A query has to be triggered by a repository/entity manager or by a controller if you are on really small-size application.

`$conn` is no way an attribute of `Member`.

I will give you the code as it has to be if it is in the controller:

```
try{
    $s = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE Members_Email=:mail');
    $s->execute(array('mail'=>$emailAddress));
    $result = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,Member);
}
```

the `PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` statement is a way of being sure your constructor will be called *before* PDO put your datas into the object

Comment: Unless you're talking about a large scale application, with a DataMapper object, I'd argue passing $conn to Member is fine.

Comment: I don't think so : SRP tells us that Member has not the responsability of persist himself. I can understand you do not want to create a useless repository but $conn hasn't to be agregated to the Member representation.

Comment: SRP is quite clearly beyond the OP at this point. Please take it one step at a time.

Comment: I was always said that it is not a good thing to correct a thing with another bad parctice. 
By the way Supericy answered well if the syntax of FETCH_CLASS is only what matters.

Comment: And I think I'm right as he is using the instance-property $conn inside a static function. That is not a good thing IMHO.